# Old Indian and Chinese references

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, mathematics-social-history, ancient-india, ancient-china

It is been some years since I completed my graduate studies in mathematics at a Spanish university. I remember one of the most pleasant and enriching moments I experienced was when reading Euclid´s Elements. This book taught me how modern maths is written and what classic geometry is all about. Also taught me a new way of thinking about maths.

Since I started learning maths, I have been curious about how maths developed in the Indian and Chinese cultures. This is why I wanted to ask the following question: Is there a book (or collections of books) that have been essential when developing mathematics in the Indian or Chinese cultures (similar to what Euclid´s Elements did in ancient Greece and Europe)?

PS: I have heard that Asians were a very advanced culture when talking about combinatory. Is there any reference for that?

Comment: On the subject of combinatorics you should study about [Pingala](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingala).

Comment: China has "The Nine Chapters on the Mathematical Art".  This is a monumental and fascinating work compiled sometime around 100 BC, and then annotated by Liu Hui in 263 AD.  I have an English translation (S. Kanghsen, J. Crossley, and A.W.C. Lun) and it's one of my prized possessions.  See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Chapters_on_the_Mathematical_Art) for a list of contents and some history.